# Postgresql Objection.js Model, need to join many to many to many

Tags: mysql, postgresql, relational-database, knex.js, objection.js

I have 3 tables Table1, Table2 and Table3.

I need to connect Table1 and Table2 with ManyToMany relation.

Then I need to connect Table1Table2 table with Table3 with ManyToMany relation.

so I create Table1Table2 table with fields id, table1_id, table2_id

and Table1Table2Table3 table with fields id, table1table2_id, table3_id.

Know I need to fetch Table1 with related Table2 and for each Table2 related Table3.

I try to did it in this way.

Table1 Model

```
table2s: {
        relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
        modelClass: Table2,
        join: {
          from: 'table1.id',
          through: {
            from: 'table1table2.table1_id',
            to: 'table1table2.table2_id',
          },
          to: 'table2.id',
        },
      },
```

I can get table1 with related table2s in this way.
But I need to get table3s for each table2s, how can I do it? Any help will be appreciated!